# Folder Hash is returning different values every time

Tags: c#, hash, md5

For my application i am using a function to hash a whole folder. When i am running this code in Visual Studio it is successfully returning the same hash value everytime for the folder that i just created.
But after i created an .exe and tried the same, it returns different hash values each time i run it. I am sure that the files inside the folder has no change. I have attached the code for my hashing function below. 
Why is this happening?? I am new here and i am not sure if i am doing this correctly, so i apologize early if my question isnt clear enough.

```
    public static string CreateMd5ForFolder(string path)
    {
        // assuming you want to include nested folders
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                             .OrderBy(p => p).ToList();

        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            string file = files[i];

            // hash path
            string relativePath = file.Substring(path.Length + 1);
            byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(relativePath.ToLower());
            md5.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);

            // hash contents
            byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            if (i == files.Count - 1)
                md5.TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
            else
                md5.TransformBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length, contentBytes, 0);
        }

        return BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

Comment: You have tested this on a folder that you have verified is not being modified in any way?

Comment: when you run this in vs it still creates an .exe file (which you can find in your `bin\debug` or `bin\release`, so it should be the same.

Comment: I am copying all the files from "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" (Google Chrome Files) to another target folder using File.Copy command. And in the end, i just hash the target folder. Chrome Browser was not opened in between, so i am sure the files have not been changed.

Comment: can you humor me, and test this with a simple folder with 2 simple text files? not sure what permissions and file types you might have in the chrome user data folder ...

Comment: Oh My.. Thanks a lot. Its working when i tried it like that. So i am guessing its something to do with the files i am intending to copy. Thanks :)

Comment: :) you're welcome. for future references, always try your theories on small cases first.